# Angular Show and hide JSON objects individually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am grabbing data from a JSON file, each object has it's on individual message. At the moment i am struggling to find a way show and hide messages separately. For example when i click on object i want to display credentials from that object only and not show credentials from the other objects.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.colors = [  
 {  
    "color":"red",
    "value":"#f00",
    "message":"Simple message"
 },
 {  
    "color":"green",
    "value":"#0f0",
    "message":"Message with <strong>HTML</strong> tags"
 },
 {  
    "color":"blue",
    "value":"#00f",
    "message":"Am I going to work? I should not!"
 }
 ]

     $scope.popupBtn = function (message) {

$scope.currentMessage = message;

if (!($scope.popupBlock)) {
  $scope.popupBlock = true;
   }
    }


   });
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul class="block-elements">
<li ng-repeat="details in colors">
  <button ng-click="popupBtn(details.mesage)" ng-style="{ color: details.color }">Click Me</button>
</li>
 </ul>

  <div class="alert-block" ng-class="{'popup-container': popupBlock}">
  <div ng-repeat="text in colors">
    <a>{{text.message}}</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you treat the data inside your view separate from the controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.colors = [  
 {  
    "color":"red",
    "value":"#f00",
    "message":"Simple message"
 },
 {  
    "color":"green",
    "value":"#0f0",
    "message":"Message with <strong>HTML</strong> tags"
 },
 {  
    "color":"blue",
    "value":"#00f",
    "message":"Am I going to work? I should not!"
 }
 ]
 
   $scope.currentMessage = "";

   $scope.popupBtn = function (message) {

     // set current message
     $scope.currentMessage = message;

     // if popup is not open, open it
     if (!($scope.popupBlcok)){

       $scope.popupBlock = true;

     }
   }


 });
```

```css
.alert-block {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  display: none;
 }

.popup-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul class="block-elements">
    <li ng-repeat="details in colors">
      <button ng-click="popupBtn(details.message)" ng-style="{ color: details.color }">Click Me</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="alert-block" ng-class="{'popup-container': popupBlock}">
    <div>
      <a>{{currentMessage}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: button ng-click="popupBtn({{mesage}})"  this give me an error message

Comment: oops! `popupBtn(details.message)` should do it. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have got rid of the error messages however <a>{{currentMessage}}</a> isn't showing revealing any data. My ng-binding remains blank. Would you be able to provide an example in codepen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` directive:

```
<a ng-show = "YOUR_CONDITION">{{text.message}}</a>
```

replace `YOUR_CONDICTION` with your condition, for example:

```
ng-show = "text.color == red"
```

Hopes that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use an Angular accordion from the Angular UI components: http://angularui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
  <div ng-repeat="text in colors">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="{{text.color}}" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      {{{text.message}}}
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

An example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ttdSZmEWJwwfBwuHTghG?p=preview

This will give you what you're looking for I think - to show only the "opened" message, and hiding the others.

Alternatively, you could roll your own directive that loops through the siblings and hides all the messages, then shows the selected message.